# How to display answer to a greaterInt in a label using Swift?

Tags: ios, swift

I have the user input numbers into some textFields. Then I make some combinations out of them and then do a series of finding of finding which number is greater than the other. For example out of a and b which is greater, then out of c and d which is greater. Then out of the the two winners which is greater from that. I want my ultimate answer to be displayed in a label on a different viewController, but am having trouble with this.
I created a struct called "help" in a swift file called "PrisonerModel.swift" and want the answer to be displayed in the answer label on MatrixViewController. I believe my problem is coming up something in the process of calling the answer.

My code:

```
import Foundation

struct PrisonerModel {
    var x: String
    var y: String
    var z: String
    var a: String
    var b: String
    var c: String
    var d: String
    var e: String
    var answer: String
}

struct help {
    var f: String
    func greaterInt(x: Int, _ y: Int) -> Int {
        if x > y {
            return x}
        return y

}}
```

Second ViewController

```
class MatrixViewController: UIViewController {


@IBOutlet weak var P1CoopCoop: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var P2CoopCoop: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var P1DefCoop: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var P2DefCoop: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var P1CoopDef: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var P2CoopDef: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var P1DefDef: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var P2DefDef: UILabel!


@IBOutlet weak var answer1: UILabel!



var labelText1 = ""
var model: PrisonerModel?
var answer: help?

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    P1CoopCoop.text = model?.x
    P2CoopCoop.text = model?.y
    P1DefCoop.text = model?.z
    P2DefCoop.text = model?.a
    P1CoopDef.text = model?.b
    P2CoopDef.text = model?.c
    P1DefDef.text = model?.d
    P2DefDef.text = model?.e

    answer1.text = answer?.f
```

**Segue**

```
prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) { 
    if segue.identifier == "showMatrix" { 
        if let matrixVC = segue.destinationViewController as? MatrixViewController { 
            let pm = PrisonerModel(x: Text3.text ?? "", y: Text3.text ?? "", z: Text4.text ?? "", a: Text1.text ?? "", b: Text1.text ?? "", c: Text4.text ?? "", d: Text2.text ?? "", e: Text2.text ?? "", answer: String(Int(Text1.text! + Text3.text!)) ?? "") 
            matrixVC.model = pm
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you storing `String`s instead of `Int`s ? How are you moving from the first to second view controller?  Where do you assign the `model` values? Where do you compute the "answer"?

Comment: We have them as Strings because we are using textFields to receive the inputs. To move between viewcontrollers we are using a segue and

Comment: override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        if segue.identifier == "showMatrix" {
            if let matrixVC = segue.destinationViewController as? MatrixViewController {
                let pm = PrisonerModel(x: Text3.text ?? "", y: Text3.text ?? "", z: Text4.text ?? "", a: Text1.text ?? "", b: Text1.text ?? "", c: Text4.text ?? "", d: Text2.text ?? "", e: Text2.text ?? "", answer: String(Int(Text1.text! + Text3.text!)) ?? "")
                matrixVC.model = pm

Comment: We are attempting to calculate our answer in the struct 'help'

Comment: In future, please [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/42741309/edit) your question to include additional code so that it can be formatted correctly

Answer (score 0):

It isn't clear what the "answer" should be, but some general advice is to convert your text values to integers so that you can perform appropriate mathematical operations on them.

I would implement `func shouldPerformSegue(withIdentifier identifier: String, 
                 sender: Any?) -> Bool` to first validate your inputs and create your model:

```
struct PrisonerModel {
    var x: Int
    var y: Int
    var z: Int
    var a: Int
    var b: Int
    var c: Int
    var d: Int
    var e: Int
    var answer: Int
}

var model: PrisonerModel?

override func shouldPerformSegue(withIdentifier identifier: String, 
             sender: Any?) -> Bool {
    if let identifier == "showMatrix" {
        guard let a = Int(text1.text!),
              let b = Int(text1.text!),
              let c = Int(text4.text!),
              let d = Int(text2.text!),
              let e = Int(text2.text!),
              let x = Int(text3.text!),
              let y = Int(text3.text!),
              let z = Int(text4.text!),
              let answer = Int(text1.text + text3.txt) else {
                  // Probably set some text in a label informing the user that their input is invalid
                  return false
              }

              self.model = PrisonerModel(x:x, y:y, z:z, a:a, b:b, c:c, d:d, e:e, answer:answe)
              return true
        }
    }
    return false
}

override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) { 
    if segue.identifier == "showMatrix" { 
         if let matrixVC = segue.destinationViewController as? MatrixViewController,
            let model = self.model {
             matrixVC.model = model
         }
    }
}
```

**Note** I have changed the name of your text field properties to start with a lower case letter as is convention.  Also your code would possibly be clearer if you had better names for your model properties than a,b,c etc.
Also the use of the force unwrap for the `text` properties is safe unless you have explicitly assigned `nil` to the property; by default a UITextField will have a string assigned to `text`.